# Overriding -handlePan: in UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

Is it ok to override -handlePan: in a UIScrollView subclass?
i.e. my app won't get rejected from the app store?

Thanks for sharing your views.

Edit: what about calling -handlePan: in another method of my subclass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, what I did instead of overriding was disabling the default UIPanGestureRecognizer and adding another instance of UIPanGestureRecognizer which is mapped to my custom handler.

Edit for twerdster:

I did it like this

```
//disables the built-in pan gesture
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in scrollView.gestureRecognizers){
  if ([gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]){
    gesture.enabled = NO;
  }
}

//add your own
UIPanGestureRecognizer *myPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] init...];
//customize myPan here
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:myPan];
[myPan release];
```

Comment: How did you disable the default and how did you specify the new behaviour so that it fits with the old behaviour and adds your own handler?

Comment: Great, Thanks, that works. Problem is that I actually still need the default behaviour of the scrollviews pangesturerecognizer so at the moment the only option i have is to override handlepan and call its super.

Comment: Yeah, I needed that too. So I mimicked that behaviour with my own code. Sounds like a waste, but I was able to do what I need to do. Its not so hard, you can do it too. :)

Comment: As far as I can tell I have to simulate the velocity of the scrollview using the end velocity of the pangesturerecognizer and call the scrollviewdidscroll method until the velocity hits zero. Is that correct? And also obviously the zooming needs to use a pinch gesture and call the viewforzoominginscrollview. Anything else really important?

Comment: The code above does not disable the built-in UIPinchGestureRecognizer, so you will still have the default zooming enabled. You still have to implement -viewForZoomingInScrollView on your delegate, of course. For the scrolling, you're right. Just play around with the velocity and transform properties of the UIPanGestureRecognizer to adjust scrollView.contentOffset. Good luck to you! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can make the code even shorter.

```
//disables the built-in pan gesture
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

//add your own
UIPanGestureRecognizer *myPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] init...];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:myPan];
[myPan release];
```

Comment: The panGestureRecognizer property is only added in iOS 5. I made the code above for iOS 3.2, so that was the only way to do it then. Nice tip, nonetheless.